# How is Visual Studio Code choosing to highlight this variable in blue vs white?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

These expressions are equivalent, but VSCode highlights "someVariable" in blue the first time and white the second time

[image: variable]

```
        someVariable (blue) := 0
        
        someVariable (blue) = someVariable (white) + 1
        someVariable (white) += 1
```

Comment: Have you installed [Go extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=golang.Go) on your VSCode?

Comment: use the TextMate Scope inspector to find out what the syntax highlight uses as scope